# How to simplify this sequence? $\sqrt{n^{2} + n} -n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find the limit of the following sequence.

$$\sqrt{n^{2} + n} -n $$

Why won't the nth term test work for it directly?  That is, if I multiply it by
$$\frac{1}{n}$$

It results in $0$, when the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about, but just multiply by the conjugate and you'll get the result.

Comment: Why do you have to do that?

Comment: A lot of times in mathematics, as you'll see in analysis, adding zero in a clever way will give you what you need. In the case of limits, usually multiplying by $1$ in a clever way, will also simplify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{n^2+n}-n \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n} = \frac{n^2+n-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n} = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n} = \frac{\frac{n}{n}}{\sqrt{\frac{n^2+n}{n^2}}+\frac{n}{n}}$$

Now just take limits as $n \to \infty$ and you are done.

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis There is no L'Hospital's being used here! If you simplify the quantity under the square root you get; $$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$$

Comment: Thank you, Faraad, for your reply!  Why did you multiply it by the conjugate?  Why was my solution incorrect?

Comment: @DonShrinkle; The n-th term test is a test for divergence. What were you trying to do with it?

Comment: I apologize, as I appear to have the wrong terminology.  How did you simplify what was under the radical?

Comment: @DonShrinkle: I think the step you are interested in is; $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}}{n} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}}{\sqrt{n^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{n^2+n}{n^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\sqrt{n(n+1)}=n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$
As $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$
So, applying binomial approximation for $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$, we get
$$\sqrt{n(n+1)}\approx n(1+\frac{1}{2n})$$
And hence, 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n(n+1)}-n=\lim_{n \to \infty} n(1+\frac{1}{2n})-n=\color{green}{\frac{1}{2}} $$

Comment: Be careful about using "$=$" (equals) when you mean "$\approx$" (approximately equal to).

Comment: I see, I always tend to forget that